# No consigo contectarme a la base de datos de AWS RDS

Tags: aws, amazon-rds

He creado una instancia de base de datos en AWS de la capa gratuita para hacer un proyecto y de esta forma experimentar un poco con AWS.

En la configuración de conectividad, he puesto que sea "Accesible públicamente"
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando voy a "Conectividad y seguridad" intento conectarme con estos los datos que aparecen aquí:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con el nombre de usuario que tengo en la sección "Nombre de usuario maestro"
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dicho usuario y contraseña aparecen cuando voy a ver el "Valor del secreto"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo tanto con el cliente de Windows de Mysql, como intentando conectar desde PHPStorm me da error de conexión por timeout:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Me estoy dejando algún paso por hacer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es por que en la sección de VPC Security Group (Firewall) que escogiste al crear la instancia de RDS  esta bloqueando el puerto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**`Solución:`**

Paso 1: Identificar el Security Group que esta asignado a la Instancia de RDS, dependiendo si elegiste la opción de `choose existing` o la de `Create new`. Observa que en mi caso tengo el default:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Paso 2: clic en las letras azules donde dice `sg-2a72684e` debe mostrarte algo similar al siguiente imagen, selecciona en la parte izquierda el check azul y debe mostrarte algo similar a esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En esa misma ventana te posicionas en la parte de abajo donde dice `Inbound rules` da clic donde dice `edit inbound rules` y aparecerá una nueva ventana.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Paso 3: En esta ventana agregas una nueva regla en `Add rule` en la columna de `type` elige la opción de `MySQL/Aurora` y en la columna de `source` coloca la Dirección `IP` desde donde te conectaras a la BASE (Debes poner tu IP pública), también puedes colocar `0.0.0.0/0` pero no es una buena practica.

Para finalizar clic en `Save rules`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Paso 4: En PHPStrom, verifican nuevamente la conexión, ya tendrás  acceso. Si tienes algun problema con el Certificado sigue el paso 5

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Paso 5 (Para RDS MSQL SERVER): En PHPStrom en la parte de `URL` agrega esto al final `;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true;`

La url por ejemplo debería quedar así:

```
mycompany-db-instance.c3j4h5i6j7.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]